# How to show the x box on the top right of image to delete it

Tags: css

I want to show the x button on the top right corner of the image,when i click on this button image is deleted from database.how can do this button with css

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. We try to help people who are stuck. Try to build the layout yourself. If you get stuck, post your code and a description of the problem here. We're happy to help. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your x button and your image in a container. Then give your container the same width and height as your image and set your container's position to relative:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
  <div class="x-box">
    X
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Now your div with class .x-box can be given a position of absolute, and placed in the top right corner of the container with `top:0` and `right:0`

```
.x-box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mb5huy3h/